# What's the benefits of docker with Jenkins Pipelines?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins/Docker. So far I've found lots of Jenkins official Documents recommended to be used with Docker. But the necessity and advantages of running Jenkins as a docker container remain vague to me. In my case, it's a node/react app and environment required is not complicated.

Disadvantages I've found running Jenkins as a Docker container:

1. High usage of hard drive
2. Directory path in docker container is more complicated to deal with, esp when working with `ssh` in pipeline scripts

Without docker, I can easily achieve the same and there's also `blueocean` plugin available.

So, what's the main benefits of Docker with Jenkins/Jenkins Pipeline? Are there pitfalls for my node application using Jenkins without Docker? Articles to help me dive into are also appreciated.

Comment: How does containerization result in a bigger usage of hard drives? I'd say at least one advantage is that you know the environment in which Jenkins builds is the same, always. That'll save you some headache at some point, I promise.

Comment: @cbll Agreed that the stability of environment is important. But when working with apps require not-so-complicated environment node app, would you think docker is not important?

Comment: @cbll As for disk usage, when I use Jenkins + docker, it requires 9+ GB on an ubuntu 14.04 server for a node/react app which is much bigger than my prod server, and it keeps growing. Is this normal?

Comment: What size is the image itself of you do `docker container ps`?

Comment: @cbll node(606MB) and blueocean(402MB), and only the blueocean container is running

Comment: A big advantage is that you don't need to 'pollute' your environment/slaves. We have a lot of jobs, some of them are pretty complex and need a lot of tools, (maven, aws cli, ruby, python, ...). By using docker we don't need to install all those tools on all of our slaves. We just install docker and that's it. We use containers with all those tools and build are apps inside the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Jenkins as Code

The main advantages of Jenkins in Docker is that it helps you to get: Jenkins as Code

Advantages of Jenkins as code are:

- SCM: Code can be in put under version control

  - History is transparant, backup and roll-back becomes easy.
  - The code is the documentation of your Jenkins setup.
- Jenkins becomes portable, so you can run Jenkins locally to try new plugins etc.
- Jenkins pipelines work really well with Docker. As @Ivthillo mentioned: there is no need to install additional tools, you just use images of these tool. Jenkins will download them from internet for you (Docker Hub).
  For each stage in the pipeline you can use a different image (i.e. tool). Essentially you get "micro Jenkins agents" which only exists temporary. This makes your Jenkins setup much more clean.

Disadvantage is:

- Jenkins initial (Groovy) configuration is poorly documented on the web.

## Simple Node setup

Most arguments also holds for a simple Node setup.

- Change the node version or run multiple job each with a different Node version becomes easy.
- Add your Jenkinsfile inside the Node repo. So everyone with a Jenkins+Docker setup can run your CI/CD.
- And finaly: gather knowledge on running your app inside a container will enable your to run your production app in Docker in the future.

## Getting started

A while ago I have written an small blog on [how to get started with Jenkins and Docker](https://cinqict.nl/building-a-jenkins-development-docker-image/), i.e. create a Jenkins image for development which you can launch and destroy in seconds.